# html tags inside jquery .html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a problem with the following code, apperantly i need to somehow escape some of the html contet but i dont understand exactly where is the problem and how to fix it, please help :)

```
$(".alert_window_content").html('<div style="margin-top:15px; position:absolute; right:5; width:250px; z-index:2; opacity:0;"><input type="file" id="X" name="X" onChange="GetDiretory()"\>
</div>
    <div class="X">
<form><input class="X" type="button" value="X"></input><div class="X" style="background-color:white; width:160px; height:19px; float:right; margin-right:3px; margin-top:2px;">
</div>
    <div style="display:inline-block;"><input class="X" type="submit" name="X" value="X"\></div>
</form>
</div>
<div class="X" style="display:inline-block; margin-top:10px;"></div>');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its because all your input tags are closed by \ i.e.,

you have written

```
<input ...... \>
```

rather than

```
<input ....... />
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understood your question correctly, but if you want the html tags to show up as readable content, you should use `.text()` rather than `.html()`

Answer (score 0):

if you want to have HTML code in your .alert_window_content then you need to make your HTML code more valid:

```
$(".alert_window_content").html('<div style="margin-top:15px; position:absolute; right:5; width:250px; z-index:2; opacity:0;"><input type="file" id="X" name="X" onChange="GetDiretory()"></div><div class="X"><form><input class="X" type="button" value="X"><div class="X" style="background-color:white; width:160px; height:19px; float:right; margin-right:3px; margin-top:2px;"></div><div style="display:inline-block;"><input class="X" type="submit" name="X" value="X"></div></form></div><div class="X" style="display:inline-block; margin-top:10px;"></div>');
```

Dont know if its that you are looking for